# Text change when background colour changes using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, text, timer

Below is my Javascript for changing the background colour of a website, however is there a way to change text in the body of the page when this change in colour occurs?

```
function changeColor(element, curNumber){
curNumber++;

if(curNumber > 4){
    curNumber = 1;
}
console.log(curNumber);
element.addClass('color' + curNumber, 500);
// So previous classes get removed.
element.attr('class', 'color' + curNumber);
setTimeout(function(){changeColor(element, curNumber)}, 1000);  
}
changeColor($('#testElement'), 0);
```

Comment: Yes, you should be able to change the text in the body when the color change occurs, setup a fiddle for us to experiment with. And it is definitely not a duplicate @Freak_Droid

Comment: @JayBlanchard Thank you for taking the time to answer nicely. I do have a JS Fiddle that I am currently looking at it is http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/7peJT/6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply have the text in an array, ( get it from some elements using jquery - however you want it) iterate through it and change the content inside the div using `html()` function when you are changing the color.

Simple modification of your code would be something like

```
function changeColorAndText(element, curNumber){
 curNumber++;
 if(curNumber > 4){
    curNumber = 1;
 }
 element.addClass('color' + curNumber, 500);
 element.html(arr[curNumber]);
 element.attr('class', 'color' + curNumber);
 setTimeout(function(){changeColorAndText(element, curNumber)}, 1000);  
}
var arr = ['hi','hello ','how ','are ','you '];
changeColorAndText($('#testElement '), 0);
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/7peJT/810/)

Comment: Thank you so so so much TJ you are a star!